# How to use a class to plot in Python?

Tags: python, class, plot

I am new to Python and trying to understand in how to make use of a class to plot a graph. I have 2 example programs main_program.py, which has 2 lists of data to use for x and y. The second program is called plotting.py, this program contains the plotting function for a line graph. When I run the main_program I just get a blank screen returned (Im guessing that this is probably because the way ive written the code nothing is getting passes through). I know there are mistakes in this but if somebody could help me out with some ideas I would be very grateful.Thanks.

```py
#main_program.py
import plotting

my_x_list = ['1', '2', '3']
my_y_list = ['4', '5', '6']

my_graph = plotting.Plot_Graph(my_x_list, my_y_list)
```

```
#plotting.py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style


class Plot_Graph:

    def __init__(self, my_x_list, my_y_list):

        self.my_x_list = my_x_list
        self.my_y_list = my_y_list

    def plot_graph(self, my_x_list, my_y_list):
        style.use('ggplot')

        x = my_x_list
        y = my_y_list

        plt.plot(x, y, 'g', label='line1', linewidth=5)

        plt.title('Title')
        plt.ylabel('y axis')
        plt.xlabel('x axis')

        plt.legend()
        plt.grid(True, color='k')

        plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never call the `plot_graph` method in the `Plot_Graph` object.

After initializing `my_graph`, you need to then do `my_graph.plot_graph()` to call the method which actually produces the plot.

But additionally, I would argue that a class is unnecessary here.  It would be more simple to just make a function like so:

```py
def plot_graph(x, y):
    style.use('ggplot')
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(x, y, 'g', label='line1', linewidth=5)
    ax.set_title('Title')
    ax.set_ylabel('y axis')
    ax.set_xlabel('x axis')

    ax.legend()
    ax.grid(True, color='k')
    return(ax)
```

Then, in `main_program.py`, you would just do

```py
my_graph = plotting.plot_graph(my_x_list, my_y_list)
my_graph.show()
```

Comment: Thanks - like this?                                                                                                                    my_graph = plotting.Plot_Graph(my_x_list, my_y_list)
my_graph.plot_graph(my_x_list, my_y_list)

Comment: That would work, but your class is written in a weird way, because you're passing it the plotting data twice.  Pass it once at initialization and define Plot_Graph.plot_graph to take no inputs, and then plot "self.my_x_list" and "self.my_y_list"